# FaultContract inheritance

Tags: wcf, inheritance, datacontract

I have several WCF service contracts, all of which contain exactly the same method `StopOperation`, having the same signature:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyServiceA
{
    [FaultContract(typeof(ServiceAError))]
    [OperationContract]
    void StopOperation(TaskInformation taskInfo);

    // other specific methods
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is to extract `StopOperation` into an interface, `IStoppable`, and have all my services inherit this operation. However, I have a problem with the `FaultContract` definition, as it defines a concrete fault type.

Is it possible to have `FaultContract` refer to an abstract `ErrorBase` type, and have the concrete ones specified by `KnownContract` somehow? Kind of like:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IStoppable
{
    [FaultContract(typeof(ErrorBase))]
    [OperationContract]
    void StopOperation(TaskInformation taskInfo);
}
```

No matter where I tried specifying `KnownContract`, it didn't seem to take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using a generic type ?

For instance:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IStoppable<T> where T : ErrorBase
{
    [FaultContract(typeof(T))]
    [OperationContract]
    void StopOperation(TaskInformation taskInfo);
}
```

Then you'd say

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyServiceA : IStoppable<ServiceAError>
{
    // other specific methods
}
```

Haven't tested this, but I don't see any reason why this shouldn't work.

Comment: Yup, this looks like a reasonable solution! I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: Since no one else answered, I will accept yours. I ended up not using this solution, because I don't really want to specify the error type as a generic parameter... I ended up using an [Adapter pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAdapter.aspx) to wrap different service implementations behind a common interface.